# How to insert many-to-many relationship record with custom data with OData.net to CRM?

Tags: c#, .net, odata, dynamics-crm

I'm using the OData.net library to access Microsoft Dynamics 365 OData API (v9).

We have a table (CRM entity) that contains information about another entity's language and the information if a language is the main language of the entity.

So we have the language id, the entity id and the main language boolean value.

Currently I'm creating a record to the CRM with the following code:

```
Contact contact = _dao.Get...
Language language = _dao.Get...

// This creates a new entity and adds it to the DataServiceCollection for tracking
Languageconnection conn = _dao.CreateNewEntity<Languageconnection>();

// Calls the AddLink of the generated OData context with the same parameters
_dao.AddLink(contact, nameof(Contact.Contact_languageconnection_contact_id).ToLower(), conn);
_dao.AddLink(language, nameof(Language.Language_languageconnection_language).ToLower(), conn);

conn.Contact_id = contact;
conn.Language_id = language;
conn.Mainlanguage = true;

_dao.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties);
```

The problem is that the value of `Mainlanguage` doesn't get POST'ed to the CRM and so the value stays false.

I don't know if the functionality I'm asking is even supported by the OData.net library because the documentation is quite lacking.

One solution would be to first do the insert, get the GUID of the new record, and then call update again, but that would get quite complicated because the OData Context is tracking all the entities and getting the id of the correct entity seems quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I never used OData.net library, but sounds like the `_dao` object is missing `Mainlanguage` bool value.

Maybe something like `_dao.Add(conn.Mainlanguage);` will do it.

```
Languageconnection conn = _dao.CreateNewEntity<Languageconnection>();

// Calls the AddLink of the generated OData context with the same parameters
_dao.AddLink(contact, nameof(Contact.Contact_languageconnection_contact_id).ToLower(), conn);
_dao.AddLink(language, nameof(Language.Language_languageconnection_language).ToLower(), conn);

conn.Contact_id = contact;
conn.Language_id = language;
conn.Mainlanguage = true;

_dao.Add(conn.Mainlanguage);

_dao.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties);
```

I remember something like this should also work alternatively.

```
Languageconnection conn = new Languageconnection();

conn.Contact_id = contact;
conn.Language_id = language;
conn.Mainlanguage = true;

_dao.AddObject(conn);

_dao.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `Mainlanguage` property is part of the `Languageconnection` entity (a column in the table). So it's not a separate object per se. The problem is that the OData library doesn't send the value of the property no matter how I set the value.

Comment: I have logged a few but I haven't gotten any answers. Also OData.net's policy is that questions should be asked on SO and not in github.